# Using a variable as array index - Optimization Bug?

Tags: avr, atmega, avr-gcc, optimization

I discovered a bug in my code which only turns up if avr-gcc optimization is used.

Can somebody explain whats the problem here?

*I'm aware that there are several smart ways to achieve some PWM, but that is not the point here.*

## Background Information

I play around with an LED and dimming it with PWM. To do some simple gamma correction I use a predefined array with the right values.

## Code

This is the code I use, Main contains just the interrupt init and an empty while(1) loop:

```
volatile size_t fade;
volatile uint16_t counter = 0;

const uint16_t PROGMEM pwmtable_10[64] = {
    0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 29, 32, 36, 40, 44, 49, 55,
    61, 68, 76, 85, 94, 105, 117, 131, 146, 162, 181, 202, 225, 250,
    279, 311, 346, 386, 430, 479, 534, 595, 663, 739, 824, 918, 1023
};

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
 // fade is set in the main loop or somewhere else
    if(counter < pwmtable_10[fade]) {
        counter=counter+1;
        PORTB = 0;
    } else {
        counter=0;
        PORTB |= RED;
    }
}
```

A value of 1 gives a very bright light, a value of 1023 gives a very dimmed light. The value 1023 is accessible through the array index 63.

## The Problem

It doesn't matter which value I set fade to, the LED is always bright, if I compile my code with `avr-gcc -Os`.
By using `avr-gcc -O0` the code works.

Changing to code doesn't work even by setting fade to 63 inside the interrupt:

```
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
    fade=63;
    if(counter < pwmtable_10[fade]) {
    //[..]
```

This is what works:

- Replacing `pwmtable_10[fade]` with 1023.
- Replacing `pwmtable_10[fade]` with `pwmtable_10[63]`
- Replacing `fade` with a new variable directly declared before the compare

## Additional Info

Platform: Atmega 168

```
% avr-gcc --version
avr-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
```

Commands to build and flash the code:

```
avr-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Os -mmcu=atmega168 -DF_CPU=16000000 -o moody.elf moody.c
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex moody.elf moody.hex
avrdude -b4 -c usbasp -v -p m168 -P usb -U flash:w:moody.hex
```

Comment: What happens when you make the pwmtable volatile?

Comment: Same problem :-/

Comment: What happens when you make `fade` volatile? (@TomL. is on the right track, wrong variable)

Comment: Looks like fade is already volatile

Comment: It is volatile (see first line of code sample :-))

Comment: Stupid suggestion, but why not declare fade a uint8_t instead of size_t?

Comment: You are right, this is more or less a debugging leftover :-) I tried to play around with that, but didn't get any effect.

Comment: Can you sniff out the value that pwmtable_10[fade] actually returns, maybe w/ a printf??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe problem is in PROGMEM attribute which saves const array into flash memory. To get values you need a memcpy_P() or so. For direct access try avoiding PROGMEM attribute. *pwmtable_10[fade]* gets random RAM value.

See http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html

Comment: Thanks you are right! This works now. I edited your answer and added a reference to the documentation. :-)